# Outlook 365 Web API throwing bad request error on Orderby clause in URI

Tags: c#, sorting, office365-restapi

I am trying to retrieve unread emails order by ascending from a sub folder of Inbox folder with below

**URI**

Attempt 1

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/AAMkADBjMGZiZGFAAB4xqMmAAA=/messages?$count=true&$filter=isread%20eq%20false&$orderby=DateTimeReceived+asc
```

Result - StatusCode: 400 - Bad request

Attempt 2

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/AAMkADBjMGZiZGFAAB4xqMmAAA=/messages?$count=true&$filter=isread%20eq%20false&$orderby=DateTimeReceived%20asc
```

Result - StatusCode: 400 - Bad request

If I try with Web API v1.0 orderby is working.

**URI with v1.0**

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/AAMkADB4xqMmAAA=/messages?$count=true&$filter=isread%20eq%20false&$orderby=DateTimeReceived%20asc

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/AAMkADBB4xqMmAAA=/messages?$count=true&$filter=isread%20eq%20false&$orderby=DateTimeReceived+asc
```

Could anyone advise what I'm doing wrong here with v2.0 which results in bad request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v2.0, `DateTimeReceived` changed to `ReceivedDateTime`.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Appreciate your time.